# Why can't I delete multiple values using checkboxes?

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, but I can't delete multiple values from the database.

I have one html table with all the values from my database table, and i inserted a button to delete a certain row.

But this button doesn't work, I don't know why.

I'm using MVC structure, but I'm following my own rules.

I made something like this on view (I cant post the original code, sorry)

```
function print($valuearray){ //calling the function

<table> //html table here
<tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Delete</td> 

foreach($valuearray as $key){   

echo "
<form method='POST'> //form to delete the values

<td> ".$key['id']."</td>

<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox'/></td>

<input type='submit' name='delete' />
</form>";
```

And I did something like this on model

```
function function(){

   $sql = ("SELECT * FROM mytable");
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){

$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE * FROM mytable WHERE id ='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}

}

  print($valuearray);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an HTML problem.

You have to give checkboxes names and values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="<?=$key['id']?>" />
```

Notice that the name of the checkbox is 'delete[]', and not 'delete'.

In your php part you should check that $_POST['delete'] exists:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']) && !empty($_POST['delete'])) {
```

After that foreach $_POST['delete'] value - use a separate delete statement;

```
foreach($_POST['delete'] as $delete_id) {
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id="'.$delete_id.'" LIMIT 1';
}
```

Notice that LIMIT 1 part - its great to limit your queries, if you delete smth. In this case you will delete a maximum of 1 row from the table.

In case of php & mysql database - you might want to use prepared statements with mysqli connector. But, that's for another question.

OR join them all in one query, which is a much better approach.

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,5);'
mysql_query($sql);
```

WHERE 1,2,3,4,5 - are delete_ids.

Comment: is giving me this warning: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: which 'foreach' is the warning about? IF foreach($_POST['delete'])? Well, I named my checkboxes 'delete[]', but you have a 'delete' input already, so maybe name checkboxes 'delete_ids[]' or smth like that?

Answer (score 0):

You never bothered setting a `value` on your checkbox tags, so you're sending essentially NOTHING back to the server.

You should probably have

```
<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value="$key[id]">
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- need this
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try it-

```
<input type='checkbox' value='".$key['id']."' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox'>;
```

and remove * from the delete query and use this one-

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM q1 WHERE id ='".$del_id."'");
?>
```

I have tried it and it is working fine.